# Check for 'not determine state' and 'permission denied state' of UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

This code is to check `UILocalNotification` permissions

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];
```

And

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *grantedSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

    NSMutableDictionary *localNotificationPermissions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

        if (grantedSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone) {
        NSLog(@"No Permission Granted");
        } else {
        NSLog(@"Permission Granted");
    }
```

will tell about the `permission`

But I don't know how to check for `not determine state` and `permission denied state`, the above code print `No Permission Granted` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

For UIUserNotificationType, there are only four kinds

> 1. UIUserNotificationTypeNone
> 2. UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
> 3. UIUserNotificationTypeSound
> 4. UIUserNotificationTypeAlert

If permission is not granted by the user or the user switched off `Allow Notifications` option, then you will get `UIUserNotificationTypeNone` in the types method. It's not possible to determine exactly which action user took to turn off notifications